# Php conflicts with older version

Tags: centos, php

I used these commands:

```
yum remove php*
yum install php71u php71u-cli php71u-common php71u-gd php71u-mbstring php71u-mysqlnd php71u-pdo php71u-xml php71u-json
```

and I installed php 7.1

After that i tried to install php package with that command:

```
yum install php-bcmath
```

But server returned response that:

```
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-46.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php71u-common-7.1.29-1.el7.ius.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1.29-1.el7.ius
--> Processing Conflict: php71u-json-7.1.29-1.el7.ius.x86_64 conflicts php-json < 7.1.29-1.el7.ius
```

After that i used that command:

```
yum install php71-php-bcmath.x86_64
```

And installed successfuly. When I used "php -m" command the module was not seen?

What could be problem? And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP core packages installed are the from the IUS repo (php71u) so that means you should install `php71u-bcmath` to have that module wire up with the IUS PHP installation.

`php-bcmath` is the default CentOS PHP module so it will conflict. `php71-php-bcmath` may be from the SCLo repo which doesn't explicitly conflict with the IUS PHP, but is not the one you installed so it will not automatically enable itself with `php71u`.